# C# type until you press enter

Tags: c#, enter

I have Windows Form Application with TextBox and Label and I want to type something in the textbox and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let's say show what I've typed in Label.

Example with button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        this.Label1.Text = this.TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

I need to do exactly the same but with pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> not button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i get error message every time:

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'

Comment: you must use KeyDown event. I tested, it works now :) see my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code from Jan Anderssen and it works correctly. The error "Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys" is because you are matching a character to Keys.Enter, make sure that the syntax is correct e. KeyCode.

E.KeyCode is used because in the event handler send a parameter with the value of e "KeyEventArgs e" variable and here is the key pressed.

```
private void txtText_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
{
this.lblText.Text = this.txtText.Text;
}
}
```

Did you copy and paste the code?

If so, try doing it with the events of the properties box.
Click in the textbox -> Events ---> key down ---> double click and put the code there.

Do you have more than one form?  This code may change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the text change event and check when enter pressed. 
when you identify enter, then you can do what ever you want